# Formatting string in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, string-formatting

I have:

```
Dim qte_1 As String = 20
Dim qte_2 As String = 20.25
Dim qte_3 As String = 320.795
```

I want my result to be:
 qte_1 : 000020.0000
 qte_2 : 000020.2500
 qte_3 : 000320.7950

What is the best method to achieve this?

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict.  `20` is a number, not a string. Then use `ToString(...your format...)` to show it in whatever format you want.  See [Standard Numeric Format Strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

As Plutonix said, use the correct type rather than String.

```
 Dim qte_1 As Double = 20
 Dim qte_2 As Double = 20.25
 Dim qte_3 As Double = 320.795
```

Then call ToString("000000.0000"). e.g.

qte_1.ToString("000000.0000") outputs "000020.0000"

Comment: Actually i get the quantities from sql query ,
and in the table the qte is nvarchar(20)

so now, i want to put this result in .txt file , that should respect this format 000000.0000

Comment: Well that seems like poor database design if it's always going to be a number. You can parse the result to a Double using Double.Parse or Double.TryParse

Comment: Storing numeric values as a formatted text is a very bad idea.  You cannot do math with strings, they may not sort the same.  If it is stored as text you will have to parse it to a decimal then do ToString to set the format

Comment: Some SQL Servers support FORMAT() e.g. 
`SELECT FORMAT(20.25,'00000.0000')` for SQL Server 2012

Answer (score 0):

If qte_1, qte_2, qte_3 were double (as i think they should), you could use the formatting parameter of the ToString method:

```
dim qte_1 as double = 20

dim formatted_qte = qte_1.ToString("00000.0000")
```

**EDIT:**

Try this way:

```
dim qte_1_Formatted as string = double.Parse(qte_1).ToString("00000.0000")
```

As the others told, the best way is casting the string to a number and then use the formatString into the ToString method.

Comment: No the qte variables are string

Comment: `20`, `20.25` and `320.795` are numbers. Your code wont even compile under option Strict.  otherwise just do `Dim qte_1 = "000020.0000"`  (@soukainaidrissi)

Comment: I don't understand very well what you want to do. You can: padl the string like this: dim part1 as string = qte_1.split(".")(0)
  dim part2 as string = qte_1.split(".")(1)
  
  qte_1.padleft(5,"0")+"."+qte_1.padright(4,"0")

Comment: No, `qte_1.split(".")` will fail under cultures using `,` as the decimal.  Parse the string then format it.

Comment: True, it was just an idea, but she shouldn't use a string as datatype.

Comment: i didnt understand , what i should do ?

Comment: i did that 
 Dim qte As String = FormatNumber(CDbl(r(i)), 4)
                                    stm.Write(qte.ToString().PadLeft(6, CChar(CStr(0))))
but i get only 20.0000 , 20.2500 , 320.7950
the pathleft doesnt work i think

Comment: Try this way (i edited my response):dim qte_1_Formatted as string = double.Parse(qte_1).ToString("00000.0000")

Comment: i dont understand what i should do

Comment: yes , u r right Plutonix i should write Dim qte_1 As String =" 20"
Dim qte_2 As String = "20.25"
Dim qte_3 As String = "320.795"
I want my result to be: qte_1 : 000020.0000 qte_2 : 000020.2500 qte_3 : 000320.7950